# Filter if either variable contains a character

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset as follows with 4 variables:

```
ID    DX1    DX2            DX3
1   Cold     Covid         Sickle
2   Rash     Burn
3   Resp     Sore throat
```

I want to write a code that will only include certain patients with certain diagnoses in a dataframe. For example, I only want patients who have either of the following diagnoses (cold and/or resp) as their DX in either DX1, DX2, or DX3. E.g. the output would be the same as above but without patient 2.

I know I can do a contains statement below but how can I change my code so the search variables are DX1 DX2 and DX3 instead of just DX1. I also know I can concatenate each of the DX variables into one variable but am curious if there is a cleaner way to code this.

```
DF_v1 = DF[DF.DX1.str.contains("cold|resp", na=False, case=False)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` to select the 'DX' columns then because the `.str` operations act on Series apply that over each Series separately. Then check if `any` of the columns satisfy you condition for that row to form the Boolean mask that you use to slice the original DataFrame.

```
m = (df.filter(like='DX')
       .apply(lambda col: col.str.contains("cold|resp", na=False, case=False))
       .any(axis=1))

df[m]
#   ID   DX1          DX2     DX3
#0   1  Cold        Covid  Sickle
#2   3  Resp  Sore throat
```

Comment: for future reference, how would I change this code if I wanted to *exclude* cold and resp?

Comment: another question - what if my variables of interest were for example, DX1, DX2, DX3 and DIAG1?

Comment: @Raven in that case I would just select the relevant columns instead of filter, so the first line could change to `df[['DX1', 'DX2', 'DX3', 'DIAG1']]` or you can use a list comp `df[[x for x in df.columns if 'DX' in x or 'DIAG' in x]]` if there is some pattern to the columns

Comment: @Raven if you wanted to exclude you could still use that mask and then just negate it `df[~m]` would select rows were there was never cold or resp